# How do I refresh a HTML table after editing it?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, refresh

I am making a very simple system that records bookings, everything is editable other than the 'booking number' and 'price' sections which are static. The booking number is pre-defined and the price is a variable dependent on the value of the 'number of seats chosen' column. The 'price' column always appears as undefined when I open the .html file, and I want to refresh the code after the 'number of seats chosen' has been edited accordingly. The price which multiplies is also pre-defined and static, which would mean that when the number of seats chosen has been defined, it will be multiplied by 5. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var seatvar = document.getElementsByClassName("seatchosen");
var pricepay = seatvar * 5
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function RefreshTable () {
            var table = document.getElementById ("bookingtable");
            table.refresh ();
        }
</script>

<table class="editabletable" id="bookingtable" border="1">
<tr><th>Booking Number</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Number of Seats Chosen</th>
<th>Seats Chosen</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td>
<td><div contenteditable></div></td>
<td class="seatchosen"><div contenteditable></div></td>
<td><div contenteditable></div></td>
<td><script type="text/javascript">document.write(pricepay);</script></td></tr>
</table>

<p>Price Per Seat: £5</p>
<button onclick="RefreshTable()">Refresh the table</button>
```

The table only shows one row, though there is twenty they all follow the same code. I included the headers too. I don't understand why it is not refreshing after I have edited the value of the number of seats chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

Give your id in the place of success function.

**JS**

```
$('.editabletable').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data("url"),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#your_id').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to be inserting this code? I'm a complete amateur.

Comment: Just add this code inside the script tag & check it.if you have any doubt let me know..

Comment: Still doesn't refresh the table.

Comment: @user3511137:give the id & class in the place correctly and check this.

Comment: @user3511137:Just verify this link http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8365/jeditable-datatables-how-can-i-refresh-table-after-edit/p1 , try it , if you have any doubt in these let me know..

Answer (score 0):

After command:

```
var seatvar = document.getElementsByClassName("seatchosen");
```

When you try print variable seatvar in console like this

`console.log(seatvar)`

You would get result `[object HTMLCollection]` because you cant object multiple number, just number * number

Answer (score 0):

**First thing,**

getElementsByClassName returns array of elements.
so after `var seatvar = document.getElementsByClassName("seatchosen");` 
seatvar will not contain total seats.

**Second,**

You have to calculate price and seats after button is clicked. 
That is in `RefreshTable()` function so that its value will get updated after click.

This may help you..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RefreshTable () {
    for (i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++) {
        var seatvar =  document.getElementsById("seatchosen_1").value;
        var pricepay = seatvar * 5; 
        document.getElementById('price_1').innerHTML = pricepay;
    }

}
</script>

<table class="editabletable" id="bookingtable" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Booking Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number of Seats Chosen</th>
    <th>Seats Chosen</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td class="seatchosen">3 <input type="hidden" name="seatchosen_1" value="3"></td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td id="price_1"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td class="seatchosen">5 <input type="hidden" name="seatchosen_2" value="5"></td>
    <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
    <td id="price_2"> </td>
</tr>
.
.
.
.
</table>

<p>Price Per Seat: £5</p>
<button onclick="RefreshTable()">Refresh the table</button>
```